# Yii2 - Include JS Script Only For Specific View

Tags: yii2

I want to include my js script `specific.js` for a specific view having action id `specific-action-id`. I don't want the `specific.js` to be included in every page.

For including a js script for the whole site I normally have to edit `AppAsset.php`. For this purpose, what should I do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should simply register this js file in your view, e.g. :

```
$this->registerJsFile('@web/js/specific.js');
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html#registering-scripts

Comment: This won't add to specific action.. this is a generic procedure to add a js file to view. To add based on action id we may need to go with afterAction event.

Comment: Not the best option, Create the Asset Bundle as in the other answer is the preferred way.

Answer (score 9):

It is highly recommended to use asset bundles to register external JS files rather than registerJsFile() because these allow better flexibility and more granular dependency configuration. Also using asset bundles allows you to combine and compress multiple JS files, which is desirable for high traffic websites.

So you can create a new AppAsset file and put your css and javascript files in it.

Create the Asset Bundle

In the \assets directory, we create StatusAsset.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class StatusAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [];
    public $js = [
      '/js/jquery.simplyCountable.js',
      '/js/twitter-text.js',
      '/js/twitter_count.js',  
      '/js/status-counter.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
            'yii\web\YiiAsset',
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        ];
}
```

In your view file

```
use app\assets\StatusAsset;
StatusAsset::register($this);
```

Resources
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-working-with-asset-bundles--cms-23226

Answer (score 1):

@soju is right. But you also can create specific asset bundles for use specific views. Your specific js files can be a file group on this situation you can use asset bundles and can use any views which you want.