# JS file from AssetBundle not found (404 Error) - Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I created yii 1 application and used following script in order to navigate in view file:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But, when i created yii2 application and pasted this code, it did not work. Then, i created new menu_navigate.js js file and pasted code like

```
$(function() {
        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

i registered this code in ThemeAsset using following code:

```
 public $js = [
 'Index/menu_navigate.js'
]
```

But, this code did not help me and it is not working. I could not manage to find any error. 
In console screen it is showing following error message
`GET http://all/themes/CompanyProfile/Index/menu_navigate.js`(Not found)

Comment: add  public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];

Answer (score 0):

Use '/Index/menu_navigate.js', that will help you to get correct path.

Comment: Here, other js files are working correctly, These working js files are using 'index/___.js' path and they are working correctly. But, js files which i created are not working

Comment: Have you included jquery.min.js in "ThemeAsset". Because the code you have written uses jquery and it should work only after DOM gets created. And if its still not resolved try to use registerScript function directly in view. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781463/yii2-include-js-script-only-for-specific-view

Comment: Leading slash in js and css file names in asset bundles is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If this file is outside of web accessible directory, you need to set correct `sourcePath` in asset bundle:

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class MenuNavigationAsset extends AssetBundle 
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/font-awesome'; // Replace with folder where "Index" folder is located. Path should be absolute, you can use aliases here.
    public $js = [ 
        'Index/menu_navigate.js', 
    ];    
}
```

Then it will be copied to web accessible directory and loaded from there. You can fild official docs for defining aliases [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html). It prevents you from hard coding absolute paths.

Otherwise (if file is in web accessible directory), set `basePath` and `baseUrl` properties:

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class MenuNavigationAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $js = [
        'Index/menu_navigation.js',
    ];   
}
```

Check accurately that the path from where browser tries to load this js file and make sure file exists there if path is correct, otherwise correct path in your asset bundle.

Also check path for typos.

Official docs for working with assets is available [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

Answer (score 0):

you should put the file css or js into js , css of folder
web. Then change file ->

```
class BackendAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath='@webroot';
    public $baseUrl='@web';
    public $css=[
        'css/style.css'
    ];
    ...... `code of you`
}
```